# Laravel 5.3 Build unit testing using php unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, build, laravel-5, package

I have a application developed by laravel 5.3 . Before deploying script i would like test unit test my whole application build using php unit .. Is any package or addons available to test my application build.Else how could i use the unit testing in Laravel 5.3 ..

I'm new to this .. Please any one help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel comes with a `TestCase` class which you should extend and write your own tests from:

```
class FooTest extends TestCase {

   public function testSomethingIsTrue()
   {
      $this->assertTrue(true);
   }

}
```

From the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/testing):

> You may then define test methods as you normally would using PHPUnit. To run your tests, simply execute the phpunit command from your terminal

Comment: Ya good.. I have one issue now in my controller i'm getting user id in session.. when i run from phpunit i'm getting empty session array.How to use session in phpunit testing

Comment: Have you actually logged in your user in each test? Try \Auth::attempt($credentials); Or if you want you can by-pass user login by disabling middleware in your tests (read the docs).

Comment: @I'm using login API third party it will return a user_id based on the access token.. that is the probelm

Comment: So what you need to do is create an interface to handle third party login. Then you can implement the interface with a production and a test class. The production class will call the 3rd party api, the test class will login the user directly in larvael framework without calling the API. You then use Laravel's IoC container to instantiate the correct class when you are in production environment or test environment